# Retrieve column names as single string with comma separation while formatting special characters with MySQL5.5 and PHP5.6

Tags: php, mysql

In one database I have a number of columns relating to temperature and voltage. What I need to do is collect the column names of said table and have them formatted into a single string with comma separation of which I have done. The only issue is, is that because degrees celsius is formatted with its special degrees character (`°C`), it throws out the formatting of the string and returns weird characters for what the degrees symbol is.

Actual table column name = `Internal Battery Temperature (°C)`

My sql statement:

```php
<?php
$sqlState = new ReturnClass; // class with 3 public members: $success, $message, and $data
$conn = openSQL($sqlState); // returns new mysqli(...)

$sqlChannelNames = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME ORDER BY ordinal_position)
                    FROM information_schema.columns
                    WHERE table_schema = '$device_id' 
                    AND table_name = '$device_name';"

$result = executeSql($conn, $sqlChannelNames, $retval);

for ($setChannelNames = array (); $rowChannel = $result->fetch_assoc(); $setChannelNames[] = $rowChannel);

var_dump($setChannelNames);

foreach($setChannelNames as $rowChannel){
    var_dump($rowChannel);

    $channels = $rowChannel['Channels'];
    echo ("CHANNELS: $channels\n");
}


function executeSql($conn, $sql, $status)
{
    // check result
    if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
        $status->message = "";
        $status->success = true;
    }
    else {
        $status->message = "Could not execute a query on the database."; //mysqli_error($conn); //"
        $status->success = false;
    }
    return $result;
}
?>
```

Which results in the output for temperature in my powershell console as:

```
Internal Battery Temperature (├âΓÇÜ├é┬░C)
```

Datatype for this column name is: `VARCHAR`
Collation: `latin1_swedish_ci`

How can I keep the formatting of the deg symbol?

Comment: Can you show the PHP for this?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I've added some code

Comment: Typo: GROUP_CONTACT -> GROUP_CONCAT in your example

Comment: When mis-handling `°` I would expect to see _at most_ two characters of mojibake. The fact that you have _ten_ [not counting non-printing characters] suggests that there has been a _significant_ amount of corruption between the source data and your screen. I would wager at least 4 levels of improper conversion.

Comment: This looks like a character encoding issue. I suggest you provide the SQL you used to create the table, which may use a different charset than the one used for your column `Internal Battery Temperature (°C)`. I.e., your table might be defined with UTF8 and yet that column contains data encoded with latin_swedish_ci. Additionally, the problem might be with your SQL connection. Lastly, there's the charset you declare in your PHP code. I'd strongly recommend using utf8 for character encoding all the way thru.

Comment: I tried to simulate the situation using latin1_swedish_ci encoding, making group_concat on the columns names and the °C symbol appeared correctly in the console. Try to change the column name, saving again the symbol, by copy/pasting the one from your question.

Comment: @ValeriuCiuca hmm really strange. I tried that and no luck. Also, I've tried `utf8_encode`'ing the string but it seems it just makes it worse?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. https://dbfiddle.uk/XN8O50z4 Edit the fiddle, add your data, reproduce the issue. Check `@@character_set_client` and `@@character_set_connection` and `@@collation_connection` settings.